# iMac refuses to boot, Disk Utility always says there are drive errors it can't repair -- what to do?

Tags: hard-drive, imac

This is a follow on to [the question I asked about replacing the hard drive in my iMac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7997/how-do-i-replace-the-hard-drive-in-my-circa-2008-imac). The restore from TimeMachine finished and the machine still won't boot. Just the white screen, Apple logo and spinner. I booted to the Snow Leopard DVD and ran Disk Utility on it again -- and again Disk Utility told me:

> Verify and Repair volume "Main"
>   Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
>   Checking extents overflow file.
>   Checking catalog file.
>   Invalid node structure
>   The volume Main could not be verified completely.
>   Volume repair complete.
>   Updating boot support partitions for the volume as required.
>   Error: Disk Utility can't repair this disk. Back up as many of your files as possible, reformat the disk, and restore your backed-up files.

Is this drive dead? Seems odd I could restore to it if it's dead. Should I try an older backup from TimeMachine? Could the most recent backup be restoring something so corrupt to the disk that it's un-bootable after the restore?

Edit: SMART status for the drive was fine. No problems reported.

Edit: I restored from a TM backup that wasn't the latest. A few hours before that. It still won't boot, but I get a little further in the Repair Disk function now. Mean anything to anyone?

> Verify and Repair volume "Main"
>   Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
>   Checking extents overflow file.
>   Checking catalog file.
>   Invalid sibling link
>   Rebuilding catalog B-tree.
>   Invalid key length
>   The volume Main could not be verified completely.
>   Volume repair complete.
>   Updating boot support partitions for the volume as required.
>   Error: Disk Utility can't repair this disk. Back up as many of your files as possible, reformat the disk, and restore your backed-up files.

Update: it was an issue with my primary drive. It had something going on with that was preventing it from being boot-able. Replacing the drive (more or less) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having solved the problem I can answer my own question.

It was a problem with the iMac's internal hard drive. Scanning the drive after the fact revealed a whole host of bad sector errors. Not sure why I couldn't pick this stuff up when I was trying to restore to it.

In any case, even with a new drive installed in the machine I couldn't get the Utilities -> Restore method of restoring the machine from my TimeMachine drive to work. It did the same thing with a new drive: it's just hang forever on boot, no chime, just Apple logo and a spinner for hours and hours.

The solution was to do a clean OS X install from the OS X DVD (instead of using the Utilities -> Restore menu option to restore the machine). Then, on first boot, when you first log in to OS X it'll ask you if you want to restore this machine from a TimeMachine drive. I said "Yes" to this option, it found my TimeMachine drive, I selected all the available types of things to restore (System Settings, User Data, Applications and Other) and let it do its thing for a few hours.

And this time it worked. Reboots were fine. My data is there and intact. All is well.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is a file system issue, rather than a drive issue, and you're right to consider restoring to an older backup. Unfortunately it's going to be hit-and-miss for a while, until you find a backup that works.

Once you're able to restore to a working version, I would do as DiskUtility says and backup your files and reformat the drive/reinstall the operating system, then make a brand new Time Machine backup from that.

Likely, the drive is fine, it's only something to do with a corrupt backup.